# JunOS: match "to community" to set destination-class in policy-statement?

Tags: juniper-junos, policing

Let's say I want:

```
routing-options {
  forwarding-table {
    export SORTER
  }
}

policy-options {
  policy-statement SORTER {
    term by-Comm {
      to community Comm-list;
      then {
        destination-class FOO;
        accept;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

An I can't get it working. Is it ever possible?

I've read the docs thouroughly and `set accounting destination-class-usage` properly I do believe.

An I have `from community Comm-list` and `then source-class` working (in the opposite direction) --- **UPDATE**:

So, my setup is like this: I have an MX80, a bunch of clients behind it, connection to the Internet, BGP peering with a core router (cisco let's say). My junos router already has loaded with fullview, there are communities `<ASN>:1` --- these prefixes are "the wild world" --- and `<ASN:2>` --- these are "to local IX networks".

I have defined the `SORTER` and community lists like this:

```
policy-options {
  policy-statement SORTER {
    term World {
      from community World;
      then {
        source-class World;
        accept;
      }
    }
  }

  ...
  community Exchange members <ASN>:2;
  community World members <ASN>:1;
}
```

With this statements --- and, of course, appropriate `accounting { source-class-usage { ... } }` in appropriate places --- I can see counters on clients' interfaces (defined as VLAN units under some `xe-0/0/0`).

So, I really can see these counters, they're correct (I'm using them for downstream traffic policing, I can graph them).

After this I've `set interface xe-0/0/0 unit <OUTPUT_VID> family inet accounting destination-class-usage` and defined a policy as I've described above (the very first code fragment), with `to community World then destination-class World`.

And I want to see that counter working .)

Comment: Could you add your BGP and "Comm-list" config?

Comment: In addition to this, please tell us what you're trying to achieve, not just what statements you used.

Comment: Are you trying to do the same http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6192/juniper-destination-based-cos

Comment: @Alex_www, looks like that. Thank you a lot. Sorry, I will try that later. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Question is similar to http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6192/juniper-destination-based-cos
and it has accepted solution.

Comment: So, nobody told me "this way is impossible because..." this time so far .) I have to RTFM more I guess .)